# In react, some keywords not defined but I think I defined them

Tags: reactjs

I practicing React to clone Instagram. In App.js, I tried to track email and password so I make input part that received email and password, and here

```
 const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message)); 

<Input
              placeholder="username"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

            <Input
              placeholder="username"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signUp}>
```

It should be read my email and password as a state but it did't work...

Could you help me with it? I am so sorry if I ask a stupid question. I am just getting started learning to react only 3 weeks.

Just in case, I will leave a whole code below

```
import "./App.css";
import Post from "./Post";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
// Basic Modal
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
// import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material";
// import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Input } from "@material-ui/core";

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50;
  const left = 50;

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

const signUp = (event) => {
  // This is to prevent the page from refreshing when we submit the form
  event.preventDefault();

  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //user has logged in
        console.log(authUser);
        setUser(authUser);

        if (authUser.displayName) {
          // don't updatee username
        } else {
          //if we just created someone
          return authUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: username,
          });
        }
      } else {
        //user has logged out
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      //perform some cleanup actions
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [user, username]);
  // USEEFFECT Runs a piece of code based on a speicific condition
  useEffect(() => {
    //this is where the code run
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      //every time a new post is added, this code fired
      setPosts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          post: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {/* <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button> */}
      <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <form className="app__signup">
            <center>
              <img
                className="app__headerImage"
                height="40px;"
                src="https://toogreen.ca/instagreen/img/instagreen.svg"
                alt=""
              />
            </center>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="username"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="username"
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

            <Input
              placeholder="username"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" onClick={signUp}>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <div className="app__header">
        <div className="app__headerLogo">
          <span>Westagram</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Sign Up</Button>

      <h1>
        Hello Clever Programmers Let's build an Instagram Clone with React!
      </h1>
      {posts.map(({ id, post }) => (
        <Post
          key={id}
          username={post.username}
          caption={post.caption}
          imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        />
      ))}
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: To help others understand your issue better, please clarify the issue. Which keywords are not defined? I guess it is `email` and `password`.

Comment: @Yozi yeah your right! I am so sorry miss the most important part!

Comment: Did you mean to declare `signUp` inside the `App` component? So that `email` and `password` are in scope?

Answer (score 2):

It is great that you are learning React yourself. Keep learning!

I will not get you the whole answer to not prevent you from finding the answer yourself, it is the best way to learn, and finding your own solution is a great feeling :)

Instead, I give you a hint and a book: `signUp` function is not correct.

```js
const signUp = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};
```

There are no `email` and `password` variables in the scope of the function.

[This topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) explains what is the Scope and I believe it will help you to fix your code.

Comment: I will check your link one more time! thank you so much for your help!